# Site maps in Visual Web developer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How does a sitemap help in building a website in visual web developer... and what does url.. title and description mean ??

Answer (score 0):

A sitemap forces you to start with a structure of your pages.

url is the url of the page you load when click on that menuitem;

title is the title you see in the resulted menu bar;

the Description is used as a ToolTip element for mouse over events.